# MySQL - Select 3 highest values and sort alphabetically

Tags: mysql

I have this table with thousands of rows:

```
id  |  Keyword  |  hits
1      cat         3
2      cats        5
3      castle      1
4      cream       2
5      car         12
.      .           .
```

I want to select the 3 rows with most hits and then order alphabetically.
So I want to return:

```
car
cat
cats
```

I have this:

```
SELECT keyword,hits FROM table ORDER BY hits DESC, keyword ASC LIMIT 3
```

but it only orders by hits and then if hits are equal it orders alphabetically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your SELECT - that gets only the 3 rows with highest hits - as a subquery inside another query that orders by the keyword:

```
SELECT *                    --- or just: SELECT keyword
FROM
  ( SELECT keyword, hits 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY hits DESC
           , keyword ASC    --- this is needed only in case of ties at 3rd place
    LIMIT 3
  ) tmp
ORDER BY keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery (don't know about your mysql version).

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT keyword, hits 
     FROM table 
     ORDER BY hits DESC 
     LIMIT 0,3) AS topThree 
ORDER BY keyword ASC
```